# Stomp android client

Tags: java, android, stomp

I need stomp client for android. I found and tried js client from [here](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc)  and it works perfect, so I need something like that on js:

```
var url = "ws://localhost:8080//myserver//hello";
stompClient = Stomp.client(url);
```

but I need similar for android, please suggest me something, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
-[stomp-j](https://code.google.com/archive/p/stompj/)

-[gozirra](https://www.germane-software.com/software/Java/Gozirra/), it's old but still working and you can also modify the source code to achieve better performance and functionality

Or you can try to use [mqtt](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/) as an another option to stomp.